# How to add Page Control in watch application

Tags: watchkit, watchos, pagecontrol

I have seen several apps that is using page control to navigate among screens in watch application. But I wonder how can we add that control in watch interface. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/2868441-reloadrootpagecontrollers) for this.

Here is example:

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["first", "second"], contexts: nil, orientation: .horizontal, pageIndex: 0)
```

> Call this method to create or modify your app’s page-based interface:
> At launch time. Use this method to customize the set of pages you want displayed, and to set the scrolling orientation.
> At runtime. Use this method to change the active set of pages or the orientation, adding or removing pages as needed.

NOTE: It's not recommended to uses both navigation types: pages and modal at the same time.